# iOS 8 UILabel intrinsicContentSize breaking layout constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a fairly simple custom `UITableViewCell` subclass containing a `UISwitch`, `UIImageView`, and `UILabel`. All of these are subviews of the cells `contentView` and laid out using `AutoLayout`. All subviews are centered on Y and then I create a series of left and right edge constraints to arrange them horizontally. The `UILabel` is the rightmost item and should scale to fit between the right edge of the `UIImageView` to its left and the right edge of its superview. When the text it too long to fit, it should truncate. This works as expected when I test using the simulator for iOS 7.1. However, on iOS 8.1 when the text in the label is too long to fit in the allotted space, the label pushes the `UIImageView` to its left out of position. I have never had this issue with `UILabel` in the past.

Edit: I should have mentioned I get no auto layout errors when this runs.

Below are screenshots and my code:

**Here is the correct behavior on iOS 7:**

[image: Working version on iOS 7.1]

**This what I get on iOS 8:**

[image: Bad iOS 8.1 layout]

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UISwitch *filterSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    _filterSwitch = filterSwitch;
    filterSwitch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.contentView addSubview:filterSwitch];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:filterSwitch
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:0.0]];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:filterSwitch
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:10.0]];

    UIImageView *filterImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    _filterImageView = filterImageView;
    filterImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    filterImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    filterImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.contentView addSubview:filterImageView];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:filterImageView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:0.0]];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:filterImageView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:nil
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:30.0]];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:filterImageView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:filterImageView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:0.0]];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:filterImageView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:filterSwitch
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:8.0]];

    UILabel *filterLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _filterLabel = filterLabel;
    filterLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    filterLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:14.0];
    filterLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.25 alpha:1.0];
    filterLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    filterLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    [self.contentView addSubview:filterLabel];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:filterLabel
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:0.0]];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:filterLabel
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:filterImageView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:8.0]];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:filterLabel
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                    toItem:self.contentView
                                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                                  constant:-10.0]];

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Why is trailing space constraint of label with respect to content view set -10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, the horizontal compression resistance priorities of the switch and the label are the same. Therefore, the layout is ambiguous (which is not detected automatically, so no errors at run time). When both can't fit in the available width, it is arbitrary which will be compressed. So, you were just getting lucky (or unlucky, depending on how you look at it) on iOS 7.

Set the horizontal compression resistance of the label to be lower than that of the other two views so that is compresses first.

I just tried: if you set up the same situation — `H:|-[switch]-[image(==30)]-[label]-|` — in a view in IB and set the text of the label to be long enough, IB will tell you about the ambiguity problem.

Comment: Thanks, Ken. The compression resistance was indeed the issue with this layout. It's funny how these subtle, undocumented changes emerge.